# Citation: earliest incidence of the Borel localization theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

The Borel localization theorem in (Borel) equivariant cohomology states that if $T$ is a torus and $M$ a smooth $T$-manifold, with fixed point set $M^T$, then upon localizing the coefficient ring $H^*_T := H^*(BT)$ (that is, tensoring with its field of fractions), the restriction map
$$H^*_T(M) \to H^*_T(M^T)$$
becomes an isomorphism.

The earliest reference to this result I know of is in Hsiang Wu-Yi's classic book on transformation groups, where he refers to the result as a "localization theorem of Borel–Atiyah–Segal type." It seems from Hsiang's presentation that Borel only proved this result for $T = S^1$; in any event, I've never been able to find the more general result in the *Seminar on Transformation Groups*. But I'd like to attribute it to **someone**.

**Who originated this result? Failing that, what is the earliest citation you know?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the reference trail, according to this [source](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971419):

> Borel made the key observation [1] that the cohomology of the fixed
>   point set was closely related to a torsion-free quotient. In the
>   1960’s, this was formalized as the “localization theorem” of
>   Borel-Atiyah-Segal-Quillen [2,3].

1. A. Borel, [Seminar on transformation groups,](http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/seminar/Borel,Seminar_on_Transformation_Groups.pdf) Annals of Math. Studies
   46, Princeton (1960) [Sect. XII Theorem 3.4]
2. M.F. Atiyah and G. Segal, Equivariant cohomology and localization,
   lecture notes, 1965, Warwick.
3. D. Quillen, [The
   Spectrum of an Equivariant Cohomology Ring I](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970770), Annals of
   Mathematics **94**, 549–572 (1971). [Theorem 4.4].

A more extensive overview of the literature leading up to, and following after the localization theorem can be found [here](http://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/pdf/equivariant.jour.pdf) (section 1.7). In addition to the unpublished 1965 lecture notes of Atiyah and Segal, there is a 1968 publication [4], crediting the theorem to Segal [5] (who writes that *"The theory was invented by Professor Atiyah, and most of the results are due to him."*).

4. M.F. Atiyah and G.B Segal: [Index of elliptic operators II,](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/suprema/trace/index-II.pdf) Ann. Math. **87**, 531–545 (1968).
5. G.B. Segal, [Equivariant K-theory,](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02684593?LI=true) Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Etudes (Paris) **34**, 129-151 (1968).

Comment: Thanks! This may be the wrong forum to ask, but do you have an idea how I could obtain a copy of the cited lecture notes?

Comment: no, but I added links to more easily accessible publications by Atiyah and Segal.

Comment: FWIW, I emailed Atiyah about this a few weeks after reading your answer, and he believes that the result, in this form, is probably due to himself.